# How do I snip/split polylines at chainages?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, mapbasic, linear-referencing

What is the best way to snip/split lines at chainages?

E.g I have a csv with the uniq ID of the polyline item and a start and end chainage. I want to extract the lines between the chainages stated.

I have access to MapInfo Professional, QGIS and ArcGIS for Desktop, and I am also OK at using MapBasic.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in **ArcGIS for Desktop**, I recommend that you:

1. Review **[What is Linear Referencing?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000001000000)**
2. Run **[Create Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Routes/003m00000005000000/)** on your polylines
3. Run **[Make Route Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Route_Event_Layer/003m00000008000000/)** to turn your chainage values into linear events
4. Run **[Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000)** to persist the linear events you have placed along your routes as line features

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this when work sort out my license for Arc!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this previously by counting up a path generated from a point collection until the result exceeds the chainage, reverse by one and use IConsructPoint to find where the point would have fallen on the segment, then start the next line from the constructed point.

Where this falls over is on multi part features, so ensure none of these exist.

If you selected the line by its id, started counting until you reach the start chainage and then finish when you reach the end chainage you could then make a new polyline for each chainage.

In this case it would probably be better to create an output using the input as a template rather than trying to break the original; the broken originals can't be used for successive chainages!

Comment: The asker makes no mention of having ArcObjects skills so I think this approach will not work for him.